# Scala-A function about 'contains'

Tags: string, scala, rdd, contains

If I want to have a function can be achieved on the screening of certain values.

```
E.g val strings = List("a", "b", "c", "e", "r")
val SpecificStrings = List("a", "b", "d")
```

Through the function, I will get the result:

```
List("a", "b")
```

So what should I code this function?Thx

Answer (score 4):

Just do it like this:

```
strings.intersect(SpecificStrings)
```

Do not write a funciton your self.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve the same result in Scala

**Using filter**

```
strings.filter(SpecificStrings.contains(_))
//res0: List[String] = List(a, b)
```

**Using ListBuffer and for loop**

```
val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[String]
for(str <- strings){
  if(SpecificStrings.contains(str)){
    listBuffer += str
  }
}
listBuffer.toList
//res1: List[String] = List(a, b)
```

**There are recursive methods too but recursive methods would require a new stack frame for each recursion and is not suitable for huge datasets.**